# constructed object scope (Java Newbie)

Tags: java, game-development

I'm currently messing around trying to make a game in Java. Currently, I'm working across three CLasses Main, MyFrame, and Player.

```
 public class Player {

    double FIVE_PERCENT = .05;
    double TEN_PERCENT = .1;

    double maxHP;
    double currHP;
    double maxStam;
    double currStam;
    double stamRegen =  (TEN_PERCENT * maxStam) ;
    double hpRegen = TEN_PERCENT * maxHP;

    int xpToLvl;
    int currXP;
    int currLvl;

    Player(double _maxHP, double _currHP, double _maxStam, double _currStam, int _xpToLvl, int _currXP, int _currLvl) {
        maxHP = _maxHP;
        currHP = _currHP;
        maxStam = _maxStam;
        currStam = _currStam;
        xpToLvl = _xpToLvl;
        currXP = _currXP;
        currLvl = _currLvl;
    }

    public double RegenHP() {
        while(currHP < maxHP){
            try {
                currHP += maxHP * TEN_PERCENT;
                if (currHP > maxHP) {currHP = maxHP;}
                System.out.println(currHP + ": Health Points");

                Thread.sleep(500);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("uh oh stinky");
            }
        }

        return currHP;
    }


    public double RegenStam() {
        while(currStam < maxStam){
            try {
                currStam += maxStam * TEN_PERCENT;
                if (currStam > maxStam) {currStam = maxStam;}
                System.out.println(currStam + ": Stamina Points");

                Thread.sleep(500);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("uh oh stinky");
            }
        }

        return currStam;
    }

    public int CheckLevelUp() {
        if(currXP >= xpToLvl){
            xpToLvl *= 1.2;
            currLvl++;
            System.out.println("Current Level: " + currLvl);
            System.out.println("XP to next level: " + xpToLvl);
        }
        return currLvl;
    }

    public int AddXP() {
        System.out.println("Initial xp: " + currXP);
        currXP++;
        System.out.println("Post xp: " + currXP);

        CheckLevelUp();

        return currXP;
    }
}
```

My issue is with the AddXP(); I had wanted to call the method on the _player1 object initialized in Main, but the issue is more with how. I wanted to add a JButton in the MyFrame class, but MyFrame can't see _player1 nor can it recognize AddXP();

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MyFrame();


        Player _player1 = new Player(40, 40, 50, 50, 24, 23, 1);

        

        _player1.RegenStam();
        _player1.RegenHP();
        _player1.AddXP();
    }
}
```

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
    
public class MyFrame extends JFrame{
    
        Player _player1;
    
        JButton xpButton;
    
        int SCREEN_WIDTH = 800;
        int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600;
    
        MyFrame(){
    
            xpButton = new JButton();
            xpButton.setBounds( 0, 0, 20, 20); 
            xpButton.setVisible(true);
            xpButton.addActionListener((e) -> _player1.AddXP());
    
    
            this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            this.setVisible(true);
            this.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(200, 200, 215));
            this.setBounds(0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
            this.add(xpButton);
    
        }
}
```

Comment: You can create a constrcutor in MyFrame which takes a Player and assign it to a field in MyFrame. I suggest doing some Java tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyFrame myFrame = new MyFrame();

    myFrame._player1 = new Player(40, 40, 50, 50, 24, 23, 1);

    myFrame._player1.RegenStam();
    myFrame._player1.RegenHP();
    myFrame._player1.AddXP();
}
```